# Read Several Barcodes Continuously on Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, barcode

I have used the zxing mobile scanner to scan barcodes before and it works perfectly (I have a button you press it and the camera opens for you to scan the barcode and then it closes and the code is sent to a specific textbox and thats it). But the problem is that if i want to read several barcodes i have to repeat this process over and over again.
What i want is to do the same and when the camera opens, leave the camera open and scan the barcodes without the activity being closed after each reading, and add each new barcode to a List for example. I was not able to find anything like this for android. Is it possible? If it is, how its done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZXing has a ScanContinuously() method

```
  var opt = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions ();
  opt.DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 3000;

  //Start scanning
  scanner.ScanContinuously(opt, HandleScanResult);
```

The [sample apps](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/d9995003697fbd30a4d99badfcd9a8d21dafd266/Samples/Android/Sample.Android/MainActivity.cs) included with ZXing include a demo of this feature.

Comment: The continuous scan works perfect the first time its used, but once i close it and reopen it again, it just scan several times per second, even though i have DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 5000, what is happening here?